# Reconcile load and reload Script.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reconcile this reload JS script found at Stack Overflow with a script used by my web app to read the load the script.js. Essentially the first cloudfare.com/ajax script says load the script.js and the second function says reload the script. Where source_code is the actual URL of the script.

The problem is it works 50% of the time. I know I am missing a something. It is so close.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" 
crossorigin="anonymous" async>

< function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
}
reload_js("source_code.js"); /> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It work everytime but u did mistake by forgot a "**<**" in your code

```js
function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
    
    console.log($('head script')[0]);
    console.log($('head script')[1]);
}
reload_js("source_code.js");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had to add the carrot, if you will, to get the script to work within the other. I first tried two separate scripts, to no avail. I did not try to put it in first, as illustrated above. I will give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Saidmore1 , can u validate my answer plz :)